# Graph Api call - Insert range to worksheet

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was using the below api call to insert data into an excel sheet in sharepoint site.

POST  [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite) id}/drives/{drive id}/items/{item id}/workbook/worksheets/{worksheet name}/range(address='E2')/insert

with my request body as {"values" = [["head1"],["head2"], ["head2"]], "shift" : "down"}

When I ran the api call, only blank values were filled into the excel cells.
Any clue what could be the reason?

Patch call to update the range worked, so was wondering why post isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected behavior, `POST` only inserts a cell or a range of cells into the worksheet in place of this range, and shifts the other cells to make space.

The only accepted parameter in the request body is `Shift`. Other parameters are simply ignored.

The Graph API calls Excel API under the hood, so you can check [Excel API insert range doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-ranges-insert) to see how it works.

The second `PATCH` call is necessary.

If you have blank Excel sheet, you can call directly `PATCH` method.